# Can air/gas be slowed down by friction

Tags: gravity, gas-giants, speed

***Can wind/air that is moving at average speeds be slowed down by the cause of Friction?*** Also, Can Air bubbles in water be slowed down because of **Friction?** *Please cite your sources.*

Comment: Just out of curiosity, i do see the relevance in your last statement, but are you suggesting a connection of bubbles in liquids and the formation of the solar system?

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape I added the relevance statement at the end.  It wasn't part of the original question.

Comment: @ConnorGarcia: Your interpretation of OP's question then seems quite far-fetched. OP does not indicate this is a question about anything related to the solar system.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape  Yes, probably better off as a comment: This is relevant to astronomy since gas friction is part of the model for the formation of our Solar System.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question about *astronomy* but rather about very basic physics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, air and gas are slowed down by friction since they have a non-zero viscosity.  From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity):

> Viscosity can be conceptualized as quantifying the internal frictional
> force that arises between adjacent layers of fluid that are in
> relative motion.

Yes, air bubbles in water are slowed down by friction since water has a non-zero viscosity.  Check out this youtube [experiment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sv9SIhbyloY) showing bubble rise rates between fluids with various viscosities.